# Exporting file with fopen/putcsv in Joomla 3.8.1

Tags: php, joomla

Im Using Joomla 3.8.1
I want to open a csv file on my pc, put data into it, then export back to pc.

I have tested the code and it is working in localhost server. I modified orders.php in components/com_virtuemart/views/orders

When I try to use on live server, it doesnt work for me. (code runs but file doesnt get written)

My question is do I need to remove any file protection security?

The code I'm using to open and put is following...

```
$file = fopen('d:\\WEBSITE\\files\\clientFile.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($file,$cust_ship);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the path doesn't exist or you don't have permissions to create/modify that file. Check the error message/logs.